# How can I call a subprocess in Idris?

Tags: process, functional-programming, idris

Is there some module in the Idris standard library (or a third party library) that allows one to shell out to another program? I'm thinking of modules like Python's `subprocess` and Haskell's `System.Process`.

Ideally, I'd like to interact programmatically with the process (writing to its stdin, reading from its stdout, etc.).

Comment: There is the `system : String -> IO Int` function which takes a shell command and returns its exit code. You'll need to `import System` to use it.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Sounds like a bounty-worthy answer to me

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks. Expanded it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `system : String -> IO Int` function which takes a shell command, runs it, and returns its exit code. You'll need to `import System` to use it:

```
import System

main : IO ()
main = do
  exitCode <- system "echo HelloWorld!"
  putStrLn $ "Exit code: " ++ show exitCode

  exitCode <- system "echo HelloWorld!; false"
  putStrLn $ "Exit code: " ++ show exitCode
```

On my system the above code results in the following output:

```
HelloWorld!
Exit code: 0
HelloWorld!
Exit code: 256
```

I'd expect it to return `1` instead of `256` in the second case. At least it's what `echo $?` shows.

---

Another version can be made basing on the `Effects` library, which is described in [this](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/effects/index.html) tutorial:

```
import Effects
import Effect.System
import Effect.StdIO

execAndPrint : (cmd : String) -> Eff () [STDIO, SYSTEM]
execAndPrint cmd = do
  exitCode <- system cmd
  putStrLn $ "Exit code: " ++ show exitCode

script : Eff () [STDIO, SYSTEM]
script = do
  execAndPrint "echo HelloWorld!"
  execAndPrint "sh -c \"echo HelloWorld!; exit 1\""

main : IO ()
main = run script
```

Here we need to explain to Idris that it needs the `Effects` package:

```
idris -p effects <filename.idr>
```

---

I'm not aware of any Idris library that lets you easily work with stdin/stdout of a subprocess. As a workaround we can use the pipes facilities of C, utilizing its `popen` / `pclose` functions, which aready have bindings in the Idris standard library.
Let me show how we could, for example, read from stdout of a subprocess (please bear in mind that it's a simple snippet with rudimentary error processing):

```
import System

-- read the contents of a file
readFileH : (fileHandle : File) -> IO String
readFileH h = loop ""
  where
    loop acc = do
      if !(fEOF h) then pure acc
      else do
        Right l <- fGetLine h | Left err => pure acc
        loop (acc ++ l)

execAndReadOutput : (cmd : String) -> IO String
execAndReadOutput cmd = do
  Right fh <- popen cmd Read | Left err => pure ""
  contents <- readFileH fh 
  pclose fh
  pure contents

main : IO ()
main = do
  out <- (execAndReadOutput "echo \"Captured output\"")
  putStrLn "Here is what we got:"
  putStr out
```

When you run the program, you should see

```
Here is what we got:
Captured output
```

Comment: Is there a variant of `system` which lets you pipe things to the subprocess's stdin/out streams?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example on how to capture stdout. `system` is just a wrapper for the C `system()` function, so I think it's not feasible to interact with it.

Comment: Great answer. Idris needs more "getting stuff done" documentation like this. Bounty gladly given!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thank you! ))

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess the Idris ecosystem is lacking a decent subprocess library. Thanks for the good explanation, though!

Comment: Good opportunity to get in on the ground level and be the first to write a high-level subprocess lib.